# Retrieving data from twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trynna retrieve data from twitter and I read that Twitter doesn't allow users to retrieve more that 180 information (or query) during 15 minutes! I just wonder why is that?! And how I can retrieve more?!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Twitter API Rate Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting).

In a nutshell though, APIs in general place rate limits simply because if there weren't any, people could abuse them and flood Twitter's servers with requests.

Also, the rate limiting isn't the same across the board. It is [different for every endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits).

And your last question of retrieving more, you technically can't but you can use their [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/connecting) which has far more leniency in the number of requests you can make but still implements its own rate limiting (if you keep opening and closing your steam, they will rate limit you).

Comment: Can you just explain to me how threads can help me retrieving more data?!

Comment: Threads will not help you retrieve more data. Unless each thread is using a different API key, the best you could do is retrieve the same amount of requests times the number of threads you have. Your best way of getting the most data is to use streams.

Comment: Okay! But, as I can understand, I can use for example two or three keys at the same time to retrieve the desired data from twitter using threads that enable me to retrieve more data in 15 minutes!! So I can easily get more data than usual in order to store it in a database!